# using view (necessary) with where conditions (dynamically)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, view

Suppose we have two tables like A {a1, a2, a3 ...} and B{b1, b2, b3 ...}

We are using a MySQl view like

```
Select a.a1, b.b1 from A a Left JOIN  B b ON a.a2=b.b2
```

Now our requirement is that we have to put "where conditions" dynamically on some columns of A and B, so we have to again join table and putting a where condition (In current code).

Now as joining twice is increasing our query execution time and I am trying to reduce the time.

We can't remove the view as per the security requirement (SQL SECURITY).

Is there a way to handle this scenario, I thought of using functions with "SQL SECURITY" or there are any other alternatives.

Comment: What MySQL version? What are the indexes on A,B? What does your `EXPLAIN {query}` show?

Comment: Our View is working fine.... In hibernate when using view.. we have to write like "Select * from view v left join A a on v.a=a.a1 where a.a3=something".. so the resulting query is using join twice when seen from Explain

Comment: Use stored procedure instead of view.

Comment: @Akina Thanks but We already thought of using Functions... I asked here to consider any better alternative or if I am missing anything.

Comment: Function will not help. Views do not allow parameters and UDVs using - both directly and in chained UDF

Answer (score 0):

Try a newer version of MySQL. The view implementation in MySQL-5.5 was very simplistic. I've seen later versions take the view expression into account when doing query planning.

Comment: That's not possible as it might have large impact and we can't take it now.

Comment: Of course, the large impact could be positive :-)

Comment: @SaurabhSingh - If you are afraid of it, then don't use `VIEWs`.  They are just syntactic sugar; they don't improve performance over the equivalent `SELECT`.